# Checking if global variables are defined in bottle

Tags: python-3.x, bottle

Im trying to use bottle to update information on a site fed in from commands in a chat bot but am struggling to get information from one route to another while checking if the variables are defined.

It works fine until I add:

```
   if 'area' not in globals():
       area = ''
   if 'function' not in globals():
       function = ''
   if 'user' not in globals():
       user = ''
   if 'value' not in globals():
       value =''`
```

To check if the variable has been defined. It works unless I set a value using /in. otherwise it errors with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/bottle.py", line 862, in _handle
return route.call(**args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/bottle.py", line 1732, in wrapper
rv = callback(*a, **ka)
File "API.py", line 43, in botOut
return area + function + user + value
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'area' referenced before assignment
```

Full code:

```
from bottle import route, error, post, get, run, static_file, abort, redirect, response, request, template
Head = '''<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    '''

foot = '''</body></html>'''

@route('/in')
def botIn():
   global area
   global function
   global user
   global value
   area = request.query.area
   function = request.query.function
   user =  request.query.user
   value = request.query.value
   print(area)
   return "in"


@route('/out')
def botOut():
   if 'area' not in globals():
       area = ''
   if 'function' not in globals():
       function = ''
   if 'user' not in globals():
       user = ''
   if 'value' not in globals():
       value =''
return area + function + user + value

run (host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

Answer (score 1):

Bottle also has a built in solution for this.

http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/stpl.html#bottle.SimpleTemplate

Basically `{{get('title', 'No Title')}}`

Of course you can always use `dict.get(variable, default_value)` on any dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using 4 globals--which you then have to qualify with the `global` keyword in several places--simply create one dict at the module level, and store your state in that dict; no need to declare it `global` anywhere.

E.g.,

```
bot_state = {
    'area': '',
    'function': '',
    'user': '',
    'value': ''
}


@route('/in')
def botIn():
    bot_state['area'] = request.query.area
    bot_state['function'] = request.query.function
    bot_state['user'] =  request.query.user
    bot_state['value'] = request.query.value
    print(area)
    return 'in'


@route('/out')
def botOut():
    return ''.join(
        bot_state['area'],
        bot_state['function'],
        bot_state['user'],
        bot_state['value'],
    )
```

Note that there are several more improvements I'd make to the code (e.g. each route function should return a list of strings, not a string), but those are the minimal changes I'd make in order to solve your immediate problem. Hope it helps!